# Trying to recreate a Dice Game called "Going to Boston" in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to develop "Going to Boston" in python. A lot of the rules are explained in the code, as well as a lot of the code being explained in the comments. I'll answer any questions, but I'm having some issues with my output. Here is what I have.

```py
# This code aims to recreate the game "Going to Boston" for four players.
# Rules:
# - Each player rolls three dice.
# – Each player keeps their highest die and sets it aside.
# – The remaining two dice are re-rolled and the highest of the two is set aside.
# – The last die is rolled and the final score is the sum of the three dice.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# We'll use the random module for the dice.
import random
# This variable is just to count rounds
RoundCount = 0
# These global variables are being used to save the score of each player.
Score1 = 0
Score2 = 0
Score3 = 0
Score4 = 0
FinalScore = []  # We'll use this to decide the winner(s).
# Here is our class for player.
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name  # Storing their name, just to more easily identify each player.
        d1 = random.randint(1,6)  # Randomly choosing a number from 1-6 to simulate a dice.
        d2 = random.randint(1,6)
        d3 = random.randint(1,6)
        self.dice = [d1, d2, d3]
        self.SavedDice = []  # We'll be using this variable to save dice.
    def score(self):
        # here is where dice are actually coded and saved.
        # Here, we'll save the max value in dice.
        self.SavedDice.append(max(self.dice))
        self.dice.remove(max(self.dice))  # We're removing the max value, and maintaining the previous two dice.
        for i in self.dice:
            i = random.randint(1,6)
            self.dice.append(i)
        #return print(self.name,"\b's score is:",sum(self.SavedDice))
        return(self.dice)
    def __str__(self):  # Here is where we return the saved dice.
        return print(self.name,'Saved Dice:',self.SavedDice)
# Here is where we actually play.
# First, we setup the players.
Player1 = Player('Player 1')
Player2 = Player('Player 2')
Player3 = Player('Player 3')
Player4 = Player('Player 4')
# We'll use a loop to manage rounds.
while RoundCount < 3:
    RoundCount += 1
    # We use the __str__ method to show the currently saved dice.
    Player1.__str__()
    Player2.__str__()
    Player3.__str__()
    Player4.__str__()
    # We'll assign values for scoring, to be used later, here
    FScore1 = Player1.score()
    FScore2 = Player2.score()
    FScore3 = Player3.score()
    FScore4 = Player4.score()
# Here is where we'll score each player.
# We'll first append all the final scores of each player to be compared.
FinalScore.append(FScore1, FScore2, FScore3, FScore4)
WinningScore = max(FinalScore)
if FScore1 == WinningScore:
    print('Player 1 Won!')
if FScore2 == WinningScore:
    print('Player 2 Won!')
if FScore3 == WinningScore:
    print('Player 3 Won!')
if FScore4 == WinningScore:
    print('Player 4 Won!')
# Just cleanly exiting the code.
print(' ')
exit('End of Game')
```

I end up getting an output like this, and I'm not sure why. I also need to keep def **str**(self): and use it.

```py
Player 1 Saved Dice: []
Player 2 Saved Dice: []
Player 3 Saved Dice: []
Player 4 Saved Dice: []
```

Seems like it isn't looping all the way through or being cancelled somehow, and the values aren't being saved to `self.SavedDice` or `SavedDice`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  This code is not minimal, and you've neglected to include your debugging work.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
If nothing else, insert strategic `print` statements to trace the data and control flow.  Where are you expecting those lists to get values?  Do they get those values appended as you expect?  If so, where do the lists revert to empty?  If not, where is the disconnection with getting each value into the list?

Comment: Also, your code hangs after the initial output.  Please trace the infinite loop or missing input.

Answer (score 0):

You're infinite-looping on the following block:

```
        for i in self.dice:
            i = random.randint(1,6)
            self.dice.append(i)
```

Try replacing with `SavedDice`:

```
        for i in self.dice:
            i = random.randint(1,6)
            self.SavedDice.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random

# Here is our class for player.
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name  # Storing their name, just to more easily identify each player.
        d1 = random.randint(1,6)  # Randomly choosing a number from 1-6 to simulate a dice.
        d2 = random.randint(1,6)
        d3 = random.randint(1,6)
        self.dice = [d1, d2, d3]
        self.saved_dice = []  # We'll be using this variable to save dice.

    def roll(self):
        # here is where dice are actually coded and saved.
        # Here, we'll save the max value in dice.
        max_dice = max(self.dice)
        self.saved_dice.append( max_dice )
        self.dice.remove( max_dice )  # We're removing the max value, and maintaining the previous two dice.
        self.dice = [ random.randint(1,6) for _ in self.dice ] # recreate list with size of remained values

    @property
    def score(self):
        return sum(self.saved_dice)

    def __str__(self):  # Here is where we return the saved dice.
        return f'{self.name} Saved Dice: { self.saved_dice }'


def main():
    max_players = 4
    round_count = 0
    # Create set of players
    players = { Player(f'Player { i + 1 }') for i in range(max_players) }

    while round_count < 3:
        round_count += 1
        for player in players:
            # Roll each player per each round
            player.roll()
            print(player)
    # Choosing winner player
    winner = max( players, key=lambda p: p.score )
    print(f'{winner.name} Won!')
    print(' ')
    exit('End of Game')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```